# Garageband like carousel for iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I'm looking for a way to achieve a menu kind of like the one you see in the "my songs" menu in Garageband. I've seen this menu in some other Apps (Omnigraffe, for example). I think it is a pretty common thing.

It will be for, like in the case of Garageband, a project menu, in the way that you can slide from one project to the next and when you tap one of them it zooms and opens it.

No questions on the zooming, I guess I'll have to build my own segue for that.

Is there a component for that?
If there's not, any thoughts on what would be the best way to build it?

Comment: If anyone would at least give me a name to call this, so I can search for it in google. I don't even know what to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to Nick Lockwood's carousel - https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel.

Comment: Thanks, I finally created it myself with a scrollView. But that carousel looks great!

Comment: Also he has [SwipeView project](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView) - carousel based on scrollview. I really enjoy his products